# Storing Information in C

Tags: arrays, c

Writing A Library management system programs that stores the name, author, price and no.of pages of a book. The code works fine when it comes to entering one book. After entering more than one book. It only displays the information of the last book entered.
I am expecting that that it prints the information for the 2 books but as shown in the output below it only shows one.
*CODE*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

struct book
{
    char book_name[100];
    char author[100];
    float price;
    int number_of_pages;
};

int menu_choice;
void menu();
int main()
{
    char author_name[100];
    FILE *ptr = fopen("Book_Details.txt","w");
    int i=0;
    int count=0;
    struct book lib[100];
    char book_name[100];
    int cycle = 1;
    while (cycle==1)
    {
        menu();
        printf("Select The Desired Service : ");
        scanf("%d",&menu_choice);
        
        
        switch (menu_choice)
        {
        case 1:

            time_t tm;
            time (&tm);
            FILE *ptr = fopen("Book_Details.txt","a");
            printf("\n********** ADD BOOK *********\n");
            printf("Enter Book Name : ");
            scanf("%c", (char *) stdin); //clears input buffer from scanf in line 29
            fgets(lib[i].book_name,100,stdin);
            printf("Enter Author's Name : ");
            fgets(lib[i].author,100,stdin);
            printf("Enter Price : £");
            scanf("%f",&lib[i].price);
            printf("Enter No. of Pages : ");
            scanf("%d",&lib[i].number_of_pages);
            printf("\n");
            fprintf(ptr,"Book : %s by %s has been added",lib[i].book_name,lib[i].author);
            fprintf(ptr,"\nDate & Time of addition is %s\n",ctime(&tm));
            fclose(ptr);
            count++;
            break;
        
        case 2:
            printf("\n********** DISPLAY BOOK INFORMATION *********\n");
            for (i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                printf("Book Name : %s\n",lib[i].book_name);
                printf("Author Name : %s\n",lib[i].author);
                printf("Price : %.2f\n",lib[i].price);
                printf("Number of Pages : %d\n\n",lib[i].number_of_pages);
            }
            getch();
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("\n********** DISPLAY BY AUTHOR *********\n");
            printf("Enter Author's Name : ");
            scanf("%c", (char *) stdin);
            fgets(author_name,100,stdin);
            for (i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                if (strcmp(author_name,lib[i].author)==0)
                {
                    printf("Book Name : %s\n",lib[i].book_name);
                    printf("Author Name : %s\n",lib[i].author);
                    printf("Price : £%.2f\n",lib[i].price);
                    printf("Number of Pages : %d\n",lib[i].number_of_pages);
                }
                break;
            }
            getch();
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("\n********** DISPLAY NO. OF BOOKS *********\n");
            printf("Number of Books available in library : %d\n",count);
            getch();
            break;
        case 5:
            cycle=0;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Enter A Valid Number!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void menu()
{
   printf("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
   printf("               Library Management System\n"); 
   printf("---------------------------------------------------------\n");

   printf("1) Add Book\n");
   printf("2) Display Book Information\n");
   printf("3) Author's Books\n");
   printf("4) Number of Books\n");
   printf("5) Exit\n\n");
}
```

*The Output*

```
---------------------------------------------------------
               Library Management System
---------------------------------------------------------
1) Add Book
2) Display Book Information
3) Author's Books
4) Number of Books
5) Exit

Select The Desired Service : 1

********** ADD BOOK *********
Enter Book Name : The Stars
Enter Author's Name : John Not Wick
Enter Price : £30
Enter No. of Pages : 200 

---------------------------------------------------------
               Library Management System
---------------------------------------------------------
1) Add Book
2) Display Book Information
3) Author's Books
4) Number of Books
5) Exit

Select The Desired Service : 1

********** ADD BOOK *********
Enter Book Name : The man
Enter Author's Name : A Woman
Enter Price : £430
Enter No. of Pages : 2000

---------------------------------------------------------
               Library Management System
---------------------------------------------------------
1) Add Book
2) Display Book Information
3) Author's Books
4) Number of Books
5) Exit

Select The Desired Service : 2

********** DISPLAY BOOK INFORMATION *********
Book Name : The man

Author Name : A Woman

Price : 430.00
Number of Pages : 2000

Book Name :
Author Name :
Price : 0.00
Number of Pages : 0
```

Comment: The case for entering books should use `lib[count]` not `lib[i]`. `i` is the variable used in the `for` loops when you search and print books.

Comment: Note that `fgets(author_name,100,stdin);` will retain the newline at the end of the author's name.

Comment: `scanf("%c", (char *) stdin); //clears input buffer from scanf in line 29` does **not** do what the comment implies.  It is _undefined behavior_.  `scanf("%*c");` is better, yet even better solutions exist.

Comment: @Equilfy, Why `FILE *ptr = fopen("Book_Details.txt","w");` and never use `ptr`?  As code does not check `fopen()` success in 2 places, code risks strange behavior.

Comment: Minor: `time (&tm);` best called just before `fprintf(ptr,"Book : %s by %s...` as that is when the addition occurred, not at the beginning of the menu selection, which could have been, seconds, minutes even days earlier.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yea it was from an earlier build, i was messing with this line for sometime trying to understand how to clear the input buffer! but thanks for the heads up and also thanks for the time (&tm) tip i did not think of that tbh, however im not following you on the ptr thing

Comment: @Barmar Yea that seems to have solved the issue thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You do want to review the good comments about other possible issues with your code, but I thought I would focus in on the behavior that you are submitting as a question.

I tried out your program and experienced the same behavior.  At issue is the incorrect usage of the element index, "i", within your switch block for adding a book.

```
        case 1:

            time_t tm;
            time (&tm);
            FILE *ptr = fopen("Book_Details.txt","a"); /* Unconventional usage of the file pointer variable */
            printf("\n********** ADD BOOK *********\n");
            printf("Enter Book Name : ");
            scanf("%c", (char *) stdin); //clears input buffer from scanf in line 29
            fgets(lib[i].book_name,100,stdin);      /* "1" is initialized to "0" and is not incremented - looks like you want to use "count" */
            printf("Enter Author's Name : ");
            fgets(lib[i].author,100,stdin);
            printf("Enter Price : £");
            scanf("%f",&lib[i].price);
            printf("Enter No. of Pages : ");
            scanf("%d",&lib[i].number_of_pages);
            printf("\n");
            fprintf(ptr,"Book : %s by %s has been added",lib[i].book_name,lib[i].author);
            fprintf(ptr,"\nDate & Time of addition is %s\n",ctime(&tm));
            fclose(ptr);
            count++;
            break;
```

This index value is initialized to a value of "0" so every book entry is going to be stored within book structure array "0".  In reviewing your code, it appears that the index value to be used is "count" instead of "i".  Following is a refactored version of that block of code utilizing the variable "count" in lieu of "i".

```
        case 1:

            time_t tm;
            time (&tm);
            ptr = fopen("Book_Details.txt","a"); /* Usual method for file pointer setup */
            printf("\n********** ADD BOOK *********\n");
            printf("Enter Book Name : ");
            scanf("%c", (char *) stdin); //clears input buffer from scanf in line 29
            fgets(lib[count].book_name,100,stdin);
            printf("Enter Author's Name : ");
            fgets(lib[count].author,100,stdin);
            printf("Enter Price : £");
            scanf("%f",&lib[count].price);
            printf("Enter No. of Pages : ");
            scanf("%d",&lib[count].number_of_pages);
            printf("\n");
            fprintf(ptr,"Book : %s by %s has been added",lib[count].book_name,lib[count].author);
            fprintf(ptr,"\nDate & Time of addition is %s\n",ctime(&tm));
            fclose(ptr);
            count++;
            break;
```

FYI, when I compiled your original code, I noted a waring about the pointer variable not being utilized.

```
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Librarian/main.c|19|warning: unused variable ‘ptr’ [-Wunused-variable]|
```

Utilizing the refactored code, I entered in the two sample books noted in your text and then selected option "2" to print the list of books.  Following is the terminal output.

```
---------------------------------------------------------
               Library Management System
---------------------------------------------------------
1) Add Book
2) Display Book Information
3) Author's Books
4) Number of Books
5) Exit

Select The Desired Service : 2

********** DISPLAY BOOK INFORMATION *********
Book Name : The Stars

Author Name : John Not Wick

Price : 30.00
Number of Pages : 200

Book Name : The Man

Author Name : A Women

Price : 430.00
Number of Pages : 2000
```

This basically boiled down to review by a second set of eyes, but always be cognizant of your array index references.  And probably delve some more into some "C" tutorial literature as it pertains to file usage (open, read, write, etc.)

Comment: Yea yea i actually did as advised in the comments and it worked actually fine with some modification as well, Thanks